# $\pi$ as the base of a numeral system?

Tags: number-theory

Is it possible for a transcendental number (such as $\pi$) to be the base of a numeral system?

Comment: Possible yes, but I doubt this system would be of any use, except that the number $\pi$ would have an easy representation.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for comment!

Comment: A site search for ["base pi"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=base+pi) shows a few related questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure!  With any base $b$, the number $d_1\ldots d_n$ denotes
$$d_1b^{n-1}+d_2b^{n-2}\ldots+d_{n-1}b^1+d_nb^0.$$

It is true that the base (usually named the **radix** of the numerical system) is almost always a positive integer, but this is not a restriction.

There is for instance a numerical system based on the [Golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base).

You can also have a numerical system based on [negative integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base).

I don't know if the numerical system with base $\pi$ has any practical use, but the golden ratio one has:  you can for instance look at [Beta Encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_encoder), a system to convert from analog to digital.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, Thomas!

Comment: Is the representation in the case of a negative number unique ?

Comment: Your're welcome. Do you have a specific reason for the question? or was this just a though? I would like to know where such numerical system could come up...

Comment: @Peter as far a I remember, Integers have unique representation, fractionnal no. Note that this is actually better than positive-integer based, where for instance 0.9999...=1

Comment: And what are the digits, when, lets say, we have a "$-5$" number system ? Additionally, I do not understand the argument with $0.999\cdots =1$ and why a negative system should be superior because of this issue.

Comment: if $-b$ is the base, the digits are $0,\ldots,b-1$

Comment: In the standard numerical system, the integer 1 has not a unique representation, it can be written $1$ or $0.\bar{9}$.
I do not remember the proof, but this does not happen with negative integer base

Comment: It is not difficult to show that $0.999\cdots =1$ , it is a simple geometric series. To my opinion, no reason to favorite number systems with a negative base. $0.999\cdots$ is a rather artificial representation and this "non-uniqueness" is utterly harmless. But maybe it is a matter of taste.

Comment: Interesting however, that a $\phi$ - number system has an application, which I would never have expected.